# Writing a C program that ignores the order of operations?

Tags: c, parsing, io, stdin, getline

I want to write a C program that takes a simple math problem from the user and use different processes to solve each part, and then send the value back to the parent process. This program should not pay attention to the order of operations. For instance, if I have the problem:

`3 + 4 / 7 + 4 * 2`

I want my program to output the following:

```
Enter problem: 3 + 4 / 7 + 4 * 2
PID 20419 calculated 3+4 as 7
PID 20420 calculated 7/7 as 1
PID 20421 calculated 1+4 as 5
PID 20422 calculated 5*2 as 10
Final result: 10
```

I am having a bit of trouble parsing the equation I am entering. I am thinking of using the `getline()` method in C to help me parse input. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 200

int main()
{
    printf("Enter equation: ");
    //getline(&buffer, &size, stdin)
    //&buffer is the address of the first character
    //&size is the address of the variable that holds the size of the input buffer
    //stdin is the input file handle
    size_t n = MAX_LINE_LENGTH;

    //Line becomes a pointer to 200 bytes of memory for you to use
    char *line = malloc(n)
    while ((getline(&line, &n, stdin)) {
        //Parse numbers and operators here
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to parse the numbers and operators that I will enter from the standard input? Once I think I read in a number, operator, and a number, I would like to use `fork()`. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: `fork`? what for? Your calculation is inherently serial.

Comment: Should I not use `fork`? I generally thought that was how I would create child processes.

Comment: Unless the point of the exercise is `fork` and `wait`. (yes, `fork` is how you create child processes) Is one of the requirements of your exercise that you use `fork`?

Comment: This is how you create them. But why would you want to?

Comment: Have you implemented a reverse polish calculator yet?  It is *much* simpler, and ought to be done first.

Comment: PID 20420 have to wait for PID 20419 has finished, your wanted input isn't adapted with the notion of fork.

Comment: `char *line = malloc(n)`??  `getline` allocates, there is no need for an initial allocation unless you simply want to set the allocation size to something other than the default `120` bytes to begin with.

Comment: So for this, what could I use that such that each value is sent back to the parent process here? So far I have learned about `wait` and `exec` as well, but I could only see `wait` applying here.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thank you for the idea of the reverse polish calculator. I had no idea what that is but it seems helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight bit of a *"robustified"* addition that does grab the final data point could be something like the following (use of integer math intentional, change to floating-point if desired):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 200

int main()
{
    size_t  n = MAX_LINE_LENGTH,
            offset = 0;
    int oper = 0, v1 = INT_MIN;
    char *line = malloc(n);

    if (!line) {    /* validate every allocation */
        perror ("malloc-line");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter equation: ");
    if (getline (&line, &n, stdin) == -1) { /* validate every input */
        fputs ("stream error or user canceled.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    for (; line[offset];) {     /* loop while not end of line */
        int nchar = 0, v2;
        if (sscanf (line + offset, "%d%n", &v2, &nchar) == 1) { /* read int? */
            if (v1 == INT_MIN)  /* if v1 not set, set v1 to value */
                v1 = v2;
            else {              /* otherwise its v2 */
                int vsave = v1;
                switch (oper) { /* switch on operator, save result in v1 */
                    case '+':   v1 += v2; break;
                    case '-':   v1 -= v2; break;
                    case '*':   v1 *= v2; break;
                    case '/':   v1 /= v2; break;
                    default:    fputs ("error: invalid operator.\n", stderr);
                                break;
                }
                /* output results of calculation */
                printf ("calculated %d%c%d as %d\n", vsave, oper, v2, v1);
            }
            offset += nchar;    /* update offset with nchars read */
        }
        else {  /* read of int failed, must be oper or end */
            size_t used = strcspn (&line[offset], "+-*/");  /* chars to oper */
            offset += used;     /* update offset */
            if (line[offset] == '\n' || line[offset] == 0)  /* end of line? */
                break;
            oper = line[offset++];  /* set oper advance to next char */
        }
    }

    free (line);    /* don't forget to free line */
}
```

(**note:** you have allocated with `malloc`, and even absent the direct allocation, if `line = NULL;` and `n = 0;` `getline` will allocate sufficient space on its own, so don't forget to `free(line);` to free the memory you have allocated. (yes, here that happens on exit, but hopefully you will write programs that use `getline` in more than `main()`, so build good habits now...)

The use of the `"%n"` specifier above places the number of characters consumed by `sscanf` in that read in the `nchars` variable that is then used to update your `offset` in `line`.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/calculate
Enter equation: 3 + 4 / 7 + 4 * 2
calculated 3+4 as 7
calculated 7/7 as 1
calculated 1+4 as 5
calculated 5*2 as 10
```

---

**`fork()` To Handle Calculations**

Essentially, the only changes needed after you have your `v1, v2` and `oper` is to `fork()` the process and then handle the `switch()` statement in the child and then in the parent `wait()` until the child exits before exiting and grabbing your next set of values. As indicated in my comment, the example in `man 2 wait` provides a good outline of the process.

Based on your comment, you were setting `fork()` up in the correct location after the `sscanf` call succeeds. There all you are doing is adding the call to `fork()` and the validations and determination of which is the child and parent. Then move the existing calculation into the child process, and add a call to `getpid()` to add to your output. In the parent process, site up your `wait()` and then exit after your child is done.

You can implement the following making the changes above:

```
        if (sscanf (line + offset, "%d%n", &v2, &nchar) == 1) { /* read int? */
            if (v1 == INT_MIN)  /* if v1 not set, set v1 to value */
                v1 = v2;
            else {      /* otherwise its v2 */
                int status;
                pid_t w, pid = fork();  /* fork to compute values */
                if (pid == -1) {        /* validate fork succeeded */
                    perror ("fork");
                    return 1;
                }
                if (pid == 0) {         /* if pid == 0 in child process */
                    int vsave = v1;
                    switch (oper) { /* switch on operator, save result in v1 */
                        case '+':   v1 += v2; break;
                        case '-':   v1 -= v2; break;
                        case '*':   v1 *= v2; break;
                        case '/':   v1 /= v2; break;
                        default:    fputs ("error: invalid oper.\n", stderr);
                                    break;
                    }   /* output child PID with results of calculation */
                    printf ("PID %ld calculated %d%c%d as %d\n", 
                            (long)getpid(), vsave, oper, v2, v1);
                }
                else {      /* in the parent process */
                    do {    /* wait on child PID */
                        w = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
                        if (w == -1) {      /* validate waitpid return */
                            perror("waitpid");
                            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }
                    } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
                    exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);    /* child exited, exit parent */
                }
            }
            offset += nchar;    /* update offset with nchars read */
        }
```

The full example simply adds the needed header files with the remainder of the code unchanged. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void)
{
    size_t  n = 0,
            offset = 0;
    int oper = 0, v1 = INT_MIN;
    char *line = NULL;

    printf("Enter equation: ");
    if (getline (&line, &n, stdin) == -1) { /* validate every input */
        fputs ("stream error or user canceled.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    for (; line[offset];) {     /* loop while not end of line */
        int nchar = 0, v2;
        if (sscanf (line + offset, "%d%n", &v2, &nchar) == 1) { /* read int? */
            if (v1 == INT_MIN)  /* if v1 not set, set v1 to value */
                v1 = v2;
            else {      /* otherwise its v2 */
                int status;
                pid_t w, pid = fork();  /* fork to compute values */
                if (pid == -1) {        /* validate fork succeeded */
                    perror ("fork");
                    return 1;
                }
                if (pid == 0) {         /* if pid == 0 in child process */
                    int vsave = v1;
                    switch (oper) { /* switch on operator, save result in v1 */
                        case '+':   v1 += v2; break;
                        case '-':   v1 -= v2; break;
                        case '*':   v1 *= v2; break;
                        case '/':   v1 /= v2; break;
                        default:    fputs ("error: invalid oper.\n", stderr);
                                    break;
                    }   /* output child PID with results of calculation */
                    printf ("PID %ld calculated %d%c%d as %d\n", 
                            (long)getpid(), vsave, oper, v2, v1);
                }
                else {      /* in the parent process */
                    do {    /* wait on child PID */
                        w = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
                        if (w == -1) {      /* validate waitpid return */
                            perror("waitpid");
                            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }
                    } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
                    exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);    /* child exited, exit parent */
                }
            }
            offset += nchar;    /* update offset with nchars read */
        }
        else {  /* read of int failed, must be oper or end */
            size_t used = strcspn (&line[offset], "+-*/");  /* chars to oper */
            offset += used;     /* update offset */
            if (line[offset] == '\n' || line[offset] == 0)  /* end of line? */
                break;
            oper = line[offset++];  /* set oper advance to next char */
        }
    }

    free (line);    /* don't forget to free line */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Running the above with the same input will produce the same output with the child PID before each individual calculation, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/calculate_fork
Enter equation: 3 + 4 / 7 + 4 * 2
PID 18746 calculated 3+4 as 7
PID 18747 calculated 7/7 as 1
PID 18748 calculated 1+4 as 5
PID 18749 calculated 5*2 as 10
```

Give it a go and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: This is a really great solution and has worked perfectly for me. I think I am still confused though because the problem I am working on deals with each calculation being done by a process. How would I implement that?

Comment: When you have both values and the operator read `v1, v2` and `oper` above, you can `fork` a process that will compute and output the result with the PID of the current process. Make sure you see the example provided in [man 2 wait](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) to understand how to wait for the process to complete in `main()` or you risk having your output in the wrong order. Read [man 2 fork](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) as well so you understand what is shared between the parent and child process at the time of the `fork`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I tried out this idea with forking and waiting as well. I am trying to use `pid_t pid = fork();` and `wait(NULL);` after the `sscanf` statement where everything is read in, and I could not get the output that OP requested for. Could you please explain this a bit more?

Comment: I also tried placing `pid_t pid = fork();` within the switch branch but I am just trying to figure out how each value can be fed back into the process.

Comment: @PomegranateSociety I updated for you, then updated again to make it match the output listed in your question.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't completely answer the question, but was a fun little toy.  This does not handle the final data point, and undoubtedly needs to be robustified (is "robustification" a word?  It ought to be!).  As an exercise for the reader, refactor the code to handle the final output, and deal with non-integer values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
        int c;
        int last_op = 0;
        float a[2] = {0};

        while( ( c = getchar()) != EOF ) {
                if(isspace(c)) {
                        continue;
                }
                if(isdigit(c)) {
                        a[1] = 10 * a[1] + c - '0';
                } else {
                        float tmp = a[1];
                        if( last_op ) {
                                switch(last_op) {
                                case '+': tmp = a[0] + a[1]; break;
                                case '/': tmp = a[0] / a[1]; break;
                                case '*': tmp = a[0] * a[1]; break;
                                case '-': tmp = a[0] - a[1]; break;
                                default: fprintf( stderr, "invalid input: %c", last_op );
                                }
                                printf ("calculated %f %c %f = %f\n", a[0], last_op, a[1], tmp);
                        }
                        a[0] = tmp;
                        a[1] = 0;
                        last_op = c;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: In your cases, should `case '/'` and `case '-'` be switched?

Comment: @user12149354 I suppose stylistically you could group them, but it doesn't change the semantics.