# How to read numbers separated by commas where the input is of unknown length?

Tags: c

My input for the problem has to look like this : 3,5,9,6,2,8.
I have no way to know how many elements the sequence is going to have so the array should be dynamic.

I've tried reading each number using getchar and then reallocate memory as I'm adding elements into the array but getchar reads the ASCII value of only one digit at a time so if I put 11,12- it would read 1 1 1 2. It also only stored the first 1 into the array.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int initialSize = 100;
    int intCount = 0;                      
    int *sequence = safeMalloc(initialSize);
    char c = getchar();

    // reads first DNA sequence dynamically
    while (c != '\n') {
        if(c==',')
        {
            c=getchar();
        }
        printf("%d\n",c);
        if (intCount < initialSize) {
            sequence[intCount] = c-'0';
            intCount++;
            c = getchar();
        } else {
            initialSize = initialSize * 2;
            sequence = realloc((char*) sequence, sizeof(char*) * initialSize);
            sequence[intCount] = c-'0';
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(sequence);i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", sequence[i]);
    }
} // EDIT: Adrian added this as it was clearly just a 'typo' to omit it.
```

I substracted the ASCII value of 0 to get the actual number but it only read one digit at a time when I need to read the whole number ( ex: 11 not 1,1).
Is there a way to read the input without using getchar as long as I don't know how big the input is.

Comment: To convert strings to numbers you have `atoi`, don't rely on ASCII, especially for numbers with more than one digit.

Comment: @Federicoklez, standard C guarantees that the runtime character set has contiguous digits `0`...`9`, so the code isn't depending on ASCII.  But yes, use `strtol()` or similar (not `atoi()`, because error is indistinguishable from zero), or `scanf()`.

Comment: `sequence = realloc((char*) sequence, sizeof(char*) * initialSize);`  Where does the `char *` come from?  `sequence` is defined as `int *sequence`.

Comment: A suggestion here is to read the entire line with `fgets` and then tokenize the elements with `strtok`

Comment: You can read the characters one at a time and implement your own conversion to integer similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58220989/writing-a-c-program-that-ignores-the-order-of-operations/58221543#58221543

Comment: @RishikeshRaje *read the entire line with `fgets` ...*  With "input of unknown length" there's no way to use `fgets()` reliably.  On POSIX systems `getline()` is available to read the entire line into memory - **if** it fits.

Comment: Or use `getdelim` to just read one value at a time.  The input doesn't seem particularly line oriented.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is just integers:

```
while(isdigit(c = getchar())) {
    sequence[intCount] = 10 * sequence[intCount] + c-'0';
}
```

otherwise, use `getdelim` to read a value and parse it with `strtod`

Note that this requires some extra logic to handle EOF correctly (it is generally bad practice to have multiple `while/getchar` loops, since it makes that logic more complicated than necessary), but since your original code is calling `getchar` in multiple places and doesn't seem to check EOF at all, you need to refactor anyway!  The above loop gives the general idea.

Here's some code demonstrating the use of getdelim.  This reads doubles, and allows the input to be either comma or newline delimited.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* Use getdelim to read comma-separated numbers */

struct data {
        size_t idx;
        size_t siz;
        double *val;
};

FILE * xfopen(const char *, const char *);
void Realloc(struct data *);
void push(struct data *, double);
int print(const struct data *);

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        ssize_t rc;
        struct data V = {0};
        size_t bufsiz = 0;
        char *buf = NULL;
        FILE *ifp = argc > 1 ? xfopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;

        Realloc(&V);

        while( (rc = getdelim( &buf, &bufsiz, ',', ifp)) > 0) {
                char *end;
                push(&V, strtod(buf, &end));
                if(*end == '\n' && end[1]) {
                        push(&V, strtod(end, &end));
                }
                if( end == buf || strcspn(end, ",\n") ) {
                        fputs("invalid input\n", stderr);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
        }
        return print(&V);
}

FILE *
xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
        FILE *fp = fopen(path, mode);
        if( fp == NULL ) {
                perror(path);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        return fp;
}

void
Realloc(struct data *V)
{
        V->siz = V->siz ? V->siz * 2 : 1024;
        V->val = realloc( V->val, V->siz * sizeof *V->val );
        if( V->val == NULL) { perror("realloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
        return;
}

void
push(struct data *V, double val)
{
        V->val[V->idx++] = val;
        if(V->idx == V->siz) {
                Realloc(V);
        }
}
int
print(const struct data *V)
{
        size_t i;
        for(i=0; i < V->idx; i++ ) {
                if(printf("%zu: %lg\n", i + 1, V->val[i]) < 0) {
                        return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had come across similar stuff, so I didn't go through what is wrong in your code.

as we don't know length of the input, two things to do neatly
1) reading input
2) parsing it and converting inputs as integers, incase of having more than one digit
   strtok() will really helps

I did it using getchar() only, following is what program looks like, check if it helps
and can be improve upon.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{

char *input=NULL;
char *tmp=NULL, *brk;
char *sep=",";
char ch;
int i=0;
int total=0;
int SIZE = 80; /* mostly line ends with 80 chars */
int *numbers=NULL;

input=malloc(SIZE*sizeof(char));
if(input == NULL) {
   /* Failed to allocate memroy */
   return 1;
}
/* ----------- read input ----- */
do {
     ch=getchar();
     input[i]=ch;
     i++;
     if(ch == ','){
        total++;
     }
     if(i>=SIZE) {
        input=realloc(input, sizeof(char)*(SIZE+i));
        if (input == NULL) {
            break; /* failed to allocate memory */
        }
     }

} while (ch !='\n');

printf("Total input numbers %d\n", ++total);
numbers=malloc(total*sizeof(int));
if (numbers == NULL) {
    /* Fail */
    return 1;
}
i=0;
/* ------ parse and convert strings to integers ------- */
for(tmp=strtok_r(input, sep, &brk);
    tmp;
    tmp=strtok_r(NULL, sep, &brk)){
    numbers[i]=atol(tmp);
    i++;

}
printf("The numbers are\n");
for(i=0;i<total;i++){
    printf("%d\n", numbers[i]);
}
 return 0;
}
```